# Javascript calling function from table of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I'm learning javascript and I have a problem with calling function from table. Here is the code:

```
function Constructor(v1,v2,v3)
{
  this.v1 = v1;
  this.v2 = v2;
  this.funk = function()
  {
    console.log("Test: "+ v3 );
  }
}

var obj1 = new Constructor("par1","par2","par3");
var arr = ["w1","w2","w3",obj1];

function f2()
{            
  obj1.funk(); //works ok
  console.log("test "+arr[3].funk.call() ); //doesn't work
}
```

Comment: `arr[3].funk()` Why didn't you use this?

Comment: Sorry I have changed the name to arr. @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy arr[3].funk() gives me "undefined"

Comment: No, It shoudl work. https://jsfiddle.net/gy94kvLf/

Comment: That's because you aren't returning anything from this.funk - so the string concat is test undefined. If no return is given then javascript always returns undefined from a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of calling `f2()` is:

```
Test: par3
Test: par3
test undefined
```

This makese sense, `funk` gets called twice and logs the first two lines.  The third line is `test undefined` because `funk` does not return anything.  It gets called and logs its test line, then returns undefined to be logged in the final line of the `f2` function.

Comment: Rookie mistake. Thanks for explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function f2()
{            
  arr[3].funk();
}
```

The code works fine but the funk() does not return anything that's why you are getting undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to pass the context to funk. Try this

```
arr[3].funk.call(arr[3])
```

Comment: `funk` doesn't make use of `this`.  Setting it won't change anything.